# Should nServiceBus messages contain objects or just simple types and strings?

Tags: messaging, nservicebus

When sending messages with nservicebus should the messages just contain simple types and strings, or is it okay to include your own objects? If so, should these objects be lightweight data transfer objects without any behaviour?

For example sending the following message:

```
public class UserAuthenticatedMessage : IMessage {

    public MyUserClass User { get; private set; }

    public UserAuthenticatedMessage(MyUserClass user) {
        User = user;
    }

    public object Value {
        get { return User; }
    }
}
```

Where `MyUserClass` contains not just properties but also behaviour:

```
public class MyUserClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public bool ICheckSomething(string foo) {

    }
}
```

Is this okay / a bad idea? Should we be using a MyUserDTO class with no behaviour? Should we be sending all the fields explicitly in the message then turning into an object at the other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send nested data containers within your messages, i.e data transfer objects, but they shouldn't have behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and it is what my gut feeling was.  Could you explain why it is bad to use objects with behaviour so I am not just telling people it is that way because Udi says so.

Comment: Since Udi hasn't answered I'll chip in my 2 cents (hopefully he'll reply as well). I wouldn't ship a class which contained any behavior because it would be leaking that abstraction between different services. Any changes you want to make to the object would likely necessitate changing both services, also quite undesirable.